# How to use previous count of semaphore in ReleaseSemaphore

Tags: windows, winapi, data-structures, function, resources

Looking for an example of how to read the last semaphore count from [ReleaseSemaphore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685071%28VS.85%29.aspx)
Having problems creating a basic local variable to store LPLONG lpPreviousCount
into and print out. Looks like I need a pointer to the variable but not having much luck.

If you can point me in the right direction, that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a LONG variable and pass a pointer to it:

```
LONG previousCount;
BOOL success = ReleaseSemaphore(hSemaphore, releaseCount, &previousCount);
if (success) {
    //do something with previousCount
}
```

This works because LPLONG is a pointer to LONG. You must create the LONG variable as a place for ReleaseSemaphore to store the value.

Comment: doesn't seem to like that. Get a compile error passing by reference.

Comment: This code should work. Please post your exact code and the error message.